# XML parsing by DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

```
    NodeList nList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("dep");
    Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> depMap = new HashMap<String, List<Map<String, String>>>();
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList2.getLength(); temp++) {
      Element el = (Element)nList2.item(temp);
      String type=el.getAttribute("type");
      Node nNode = nList2.item(temp);
      if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        List<Map<String,String>> depList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
        String governor = getTagValue("governor", eElement);
        String dependent = getTagValue("dependent", eElement);
        Map<String, String> govdepmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        govdepmap.put(governor, dependent);
        depList.add(govdepmap);
        List<Map<String,String>> flist = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
        flist.add(govdepmap);
        depMap.put(type, flist);
      }
    }
```

I have the following structure in my XML file:

```
   <basic-dependencies>
              <dep type="nsubj">
                <governor idx="4">going</governor>
                <dependent idx="1">I</dependent>
              </dep>
```

Now i want to store the "idx" attribute of each "governor" and "dependent" tag. What code should I change or add?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
    NodeList liste = eElement.getElementsByTagName("governor");
    NodeList liste2 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("dependent");
```

If there is always one dependant for one governor you can do :

```
    for(int i=0; i<liste.getLength(); i++){
        Element e = (Element)liste.item(i);
        Element e2 = (Element)liste2.item(i);
        govToIdxMap.put(governor,e.getAttribute("idx"));
        depToIdxMap.put(dependent,e2.getAttribute("idx"));
    }
    List<Map<String,String>> listMap = new ArrayList<>();
    listMap.add(govToIdxMap);
    listMap.add(depToIdxMap);
    Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>> final = new Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>>();
    final.put(governor,listMap);
```

Comment: But this puts only numbers in govdepmap. What is need is that governor gets mapped to corresponding idx and dependent too

Comment: What do you want? A map with the governor value as key and a list of both idx as value? If it is then just modify the `Map.put` part, instead put both idx in a list and add this list to a Map<String, List<String>> .

Comment: I want that every governor value should be saved with its idx and dependent value with its idx. But presently my map is just saving governor as key and dependent as value.
Ultimately I want
Map<String,List<Map<Map<String,String>,Map<String,String>>>>
means Map<String,String> would contain <governor,idx> and second Map<String,String> would contain <dependent,idx>

Comment: @blackpearl Ok not obvious :/  I've edited tell me if it's what you need.